# kafka producer/consumer machine try to connect to itself

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have kafka cluster deployed on EC2 instance, with `ip a.b.c.d` , the producer and the consumer are also deployed on another EC2 instance (both on the same instance) with `ip a2.b2.c2.d2`, on the `catalina.out` log file of the `producer/consumer` machine i always fined the error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-a2-b2-c2-d2: ip-a2-b2-c2-d2: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1496)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:107)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:128)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:89)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer.create(ConsumerConnector.scala)
        at com.wsg.promo.kafka.listener.ConsumerClient.run(ConsumerClient.java:90)
        at com.wsg.promo.kafka.listener.ConsumerClient.run(ConsumerClient.java:62)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-a2-b2-c2-d2: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:922)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1316)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1492)
        ... 6 more
```

which state that the `producer/consumer` machine try to connect to itself (`ip-a2-b2-c2-d2` is for the `producer/consumer` machine),

why the `producer/consumer` machine try to connect to itself ? (is that normal ?) how can i fix this issue ? i already spent about 16 hrs. to figure it out, but no luck

Comment: a2-b2-c2-d2 is not ip address. you can check IP address of producer/consumer machine by command (like ifconfig for ubuntu) and put that real IP.

Comment: @Nilesh, you mean put the real ip of producer/consumer into advertised.host.name ?

Comment: Yes Exactly.. 
a2-b2-c2-d2 this is not findable or real

Comment: Add your producer & consumer IP in your /etc/hosts in all the machines. So, that the hostname can be resolved for the provided IP.